# Define a callback using use dispatch within the main component in React

Tags: redux, react-hooks, react-redux, dispatch, useselector

I have a problem that I just can't solve in React. My intention is to define a button callback that will set the value of a state in redux, this callback uses the `dispatch` function within it with two values containing two different redux states. It seems that these instructions

```js
//Saving select selected value from redux store
const selectedValue: string|undefined = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.selectedOption);

//2. Save the input value from the redux store
const inputValue: string|null = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.inputTextValue);
```

are executed before the actual initialization of the store in redux so react gives me this problem ---> "**Could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a** "

I tried to define it like this:

App.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Card } from './components/organism/Card';
import { useState } from "react";
import { Context } from './context/Context'
import { imgData } from "./context/Context";
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import StudentExercise from "./components/organism/studentExercise/studentExercise";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { optionsArray } from "./redux/reducers/SelectedOption/selectedOption";
import {
  setBirthYear,
  setCourse,
  setName,
  setSurname,
  setTutor
} from "./redux/actions";

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

// todo: cercare metodo non deprecato
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());// Reducer store

function App() {
  // States
  const [value, setValue] = useState('My context value');
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(imgData); 

  // Callbacks:
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Saving selected value from redux store 
  const selectedValue: string|undefined = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.selectedOption);

  // 2. Saving another value from redux store
  const inputValue: string|null = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.inputTextValue);

  // Callbacks:
  const handleClick = useCallback(()=> {
    switch(selectedValue) {
      case "name":
        console.log("Selected value --> ",selectedValue);
        console.log(inputValue);
        return dispatch(setName(inputValue));
      case "surname":
        return dispatch(setSurname(inputValue));
      case "birthYear":
        return dispatch(setBirthYear(inputValue));
      case "course":
        return dispatch(setCourse(inputValue));
      case "tutor":
        return dispatch(setTutor(inputValue));
      default:
        return selectedValue;
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Provider store={store}> {/* Redux store */}
          <Context.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}> {/* Esercizio card */}
            <Card />
          </Context.Provider>

          <StudentExercise 
            clickHandler={handleClick} 
            title={"changing values!"}
          />
        </Provider>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My expectation is to have a callback defined in the outermost possible component, in this case App so that I can reuse the `StudentExercise` component but with `handleClick` passed as prop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this `App` component is the component rendering the Redux `Provider` component and providing the store to ***its*** sub-ReactTree. This means `App` itself cannot access the store since there's not any Redux provider higher in the ReactTree.

Move the `Provider` component higher in the ReactTree so that `App` can access the redux store.

Example:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import './App.css';
import { Card } from './components/organism/Card';
import { Context } from './context/Context';
import { imgData } from "./context/Context";
import StudentExercise from "./components/organism/studentExercise/studentExercise";
import { optionsArray } from "./redux/reducers/SelectedOption/selectedOption";
import {
    setBirthYear,
    setCourse,
    setName,
    setSurname,
    setTutor
} from "./redux/actions";
import type { RootState } from './index.tsx';

...

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('My context value');
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState(imgData);
   
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const selectedValue: string|undefined = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.selectedOption);
  const inputValue: string|null = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.inputTextValue);

  const handleClick = useCallback(()=> {
    switch(selectedValue) {
      case "name":
        return dispatch(setName(inputValue));
      case "surname":
        return dispatch(setSurname(inputValue));
      case "birthYear":
        return dispatch(setBirthYear(inputValue));
      case "course":
        return dispatch(setCourse(inputValue));
      case "tutor":
        return dispatch(setTutor(inputValue));
      default:
        return selectedValue;
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context.Provider value={{ value, setValue }}>
        <Card />
      </Context.Provider>
      <StudentExercise 
        clickHandler={handleClick} 
        title="changing values!"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {createStore} from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

...

<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I moved the provider to a higher level and now it works!